# How can I resample a XTS timeseries with R without sorting by date?

Tags: r, time-series, xts, montecarlo, resampling

I have a list of Profit and Loss in a xts object and I’m going to run a sort of *Monte Carlo* analysis in order to figure out the maximum drawdown with many resampling of the original xts timeseries.

```
# let's say qq is a timeseries of PnL
qq <- xts(1:10, order.by = as.Date('2016-01-01')+0:9)
set.seed(0)
# I create an index vector of 5 random samples without replacing
idx <- sample(1:10, 5)
# with that seed, idx = c(9, 3, 10, 5, 6)
qq[idx] # returns
           [,1]
2016-01-03    3
2016-01-05    5
2016-01-06    6
2016-01-09    9
2016-01-10   10
```

The problem is that xts always sorts by date its elements, so is there a way to have a subset of xts timeseries with unsorted elements?

```
           [,1]
2016-01-09    9
2016-01-03    3
2016-01-10   10
2016-01-05    5
2016-01-06    6
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like their parent class (zoo), xts objects must always be ordered. There's no way to create an unordered xts (or zoo) object.

In your case, you do not need the index in order to calculate drawdown. So you can just use the object's `coredata`. Or you can use `as.matrix` if you want to keep the index values as names.

```
R> (ss <- coredata(qq)[idx])
[1]  9  3 10  5  6
R> (ss <- as.matrix(qq)[idx,])
2016-01-09 2016-01-03 2016-01-10 2016-01-05 2016-01-06 
         9          3         10          5          6
```

Then you can calculate the maximum drawdown.

```
R> ss-cummax(ss)       # drawdown
2016-01-09 2016-01-03 2016-01-10 2016-01-05 2016-01-06 
         0         -6          0         -5         -4 
R> min(ss-cummax(ss))  # max drawdown
[1] -6
```